# AttributeError: module 'plotly.express' has no attribute 'sunburst'

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

> AttributeError: module 'plotly.express' has no attribute 'sunburst'

My wrong code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 1957")
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['continent', 'country'], values='pop',
                  color='gdpPercap', hover_data=['iso_alpha'],
                  color_continuous_scale='gdpPercap',
                  color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df['gdpPercap'], weights=df['pop']))
fig.show()
```

Error message:

````
AttributeError        Traceback (most recent call last

<ipython-input-25-228e1998d41a> in <module>()
      2 import numpy as np
      3 df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 1957")
----> 4 fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['continent', 'country'], values='pop',
      5                   color='gdpPercap', hover_data=['iso_alpha'],
      6                   color_continuous_scale='gdpPercap', ```

AttributeError: module 'plotly.express' has no attribute 'sunburst'
````

Comment: can you print your python and plotly version? `import sys; print(sys.version); import plotly; print(plotly.__version__)`

Answer (score 1):

`sunburst` was added in the version [4.4.0](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440---2019-12-10) of plotly, so if you have a previous version you need to update the module

Comment: 3.5.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 13 2017, 11:22:58) [GCC 7.2.0]4.2.1

Comment: your plotly version 4.2.1 is old, please update plotly to at least version 4.4.0 to use 'sunburst'